# Highcharts continuous line pattern

Tags: design-patterns, highcharts

I have a chart using custom pattern:

[image]

As you can see, one can distinguish a separation between repeating patterns. How can I avoid that?

Here's my pattern definition:

```
    pattern: {
      path: {
        d: 'M 0 0 L 10 20',
        strokeWidth: 1,
      },
      width: 10,
      height: 20,
      color: '#eee',
    },
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can correct for that by adding some overage lines

```
pattern: {
    path: {
        d: 'M 0 0 L 10 20 M 9 -2 L 11 2 M -1 18 L 1 22',
        strokeWidth: 1
    },
    width: 10,
    height: 20,
    color: '#eee'
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/blaird/j8au01dh/1/

Comment: Works like a charm, though I'm still unclear why. I tried `M 0 0 L 11 22` or `M -1 -2 L 11 22` so that lines go further than the content box, but it did not work.